# How could you measure the rate of light reactivity/ photosynthesis of a cell in a lab setting?

Tags: microbiology, homework, lab-techniques

For a lab I must take Volvox protist cells and expose them to specific wavelengths of light. How would I know they're even reacting? The assignment I've been given does not explain what I should even be looking for. I know that they do photosynthesis, so I was thinking of looking for signs of photosynthesis occurring, but I have no idea how to tell if even that is happening.

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs of photosynthesis? How could you detect a change in one of these? How might the appearance of, say, one of the products product appear in the watery environment of Volvox?